# Custom Fonts in Ionic3

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic2, ionic3

I am using `Ionic3`:

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.4
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.1 Build version 8E1000a
```

[image]

I have the following font: `Ormont_Light.ttf`

As you can see above, I try apply this new font in the `app.scss` file. However, I cannot seem to make it take effect.

As you can see, it is still using the Ionic default of:

```
font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
```

[image]

**Question**

Please can anyone advise how to implement a new font using a `ttf` file in Ionic 3?

**UPDATE**

I add the following:

```
@font-face {
font-family: Ormont_Light;
src: url(../assets/fonts/Ormont_Light.ttf) format("ttf");
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
body {
    font-family: Ormont_Light !important;
}
```

Now I get the font showing up in the source:

```
body {
    font-family: Ormont_Light !important;
}
```

But it's not being applied to the app on a global level as expected.

**UPDATE**

**variables.scss**

```
$font-family-base: "Ormont_Light";
$font-family-ios-base: $font-family-base;
$font-family-md-base: $font-family-base;
$font-family-wp-base: $font-family-base;
```

Thanks, That kind of works. It is now applying `Ormont_Light` too all my styles which is great. i.e. the `dom` now has:

```
body {
    font-family: Ormont_Light !important;
}
```

But the the displayed font is using `Times New Roman` font, which I guess is the browser default when it cannot find the font referenced. So I guess my path to my `.ttf` file is incorrect.

Where do you keep you `.ttf` file?

Comment: Thanks for the update on this. It helped me out immensely

Answer (score 7):

You need to override the [Ionic Sass Variables](http://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/) .
You need to add this font-face in `src/theme/variables.scss`.

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Ormont_Light';
 src:url('../assets/fonts/Ormont_Light.ttf') format('truetype');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
$font-family-base: "Ormont_Light";
$font-family-ios-base: $font-family-base;
$font-family-md-base: $font-family-base;
$font-family-wp-base: $font-family-base;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm !